# Laravel webpack use a simple jquery plugin

Tags: laravel, webpack

With the last version of Laravel, I cannot use a simple jQuery plugin.

‍I try to use ‍‍‍`bootstrap-datepicker` plugin. So I used:

```
yarn add bootstrap-datepicker
```

Then, in my *app.js*:

```
import './bootstrap';
import 'bootstrap-datepicker';
```

In *bootstrap.js*, I have:

```
try {
    window.$ = window.jQuery = require('jquery');

    require('bootstrap');
} catch (e) {}
```

This should make jQuery global I guess.

But when I try:

```
$(function() {
        $('.input-daterange input').each(function() {
            $(this).datepicker('clearDates');
        });
});
```

I got the error:

> app.js:41747 Uncaught TypeError: $(...).datepicker is not a function

I have this error with a lot of plugins (daterangepicker, datepicker...)

What I have to do to use Webpack / Mix to just use one simple jQuery plugin?

Comment: refer this https://www.justin.ly/adding-jquery-bootstrap-plugins-laravel-5-mix/

Comment: Nice explanations but I got same problems using his code...

Comment: did you run mix ? npm run dev

Comment: Yes of course, when I use `mix.autoload`, nothing work anymore :(

Answer (score 1):

I made it this way:

In console:

```
npm i jquery-ui-dist
```

/resources/assets/js/bootstrap.js:

```
try {
    window.$ = window.jQuery = require('jquery');
    require('bootstrap');
    require('jquery-ui-dist/jquery-ui')
} catch (e) {}
```

/resources/assets/sass/app.scss:

```
@import'~jquery-ui-dist/jquery-ui';
```

In your blade or at the end of boostrap.js

```
$('.input-daterange input').datepicker(params)
```

In this case I'm usign jQuery UI DatePicker

Answer (score 0):

If jQuery and jQuery Plugin not in the same file, you need to use `$.fn.extend()` merge the contents of plugin object onto the jQuery prototype to provide new jQuery instance methods.

```
$.fn.extend({
    datepicker: function() {
        require('bootstrap-datepicker');
    }
});
```